# docker build purely from command line

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a way to build docker containers completely from the command-line? Namely, I need to be able to set things like `FROM`, `RUN` and `CMD`.

I'm a scenario where I have to use docker containers to run everything (`git`, `npm`, etc), and I'd like to build containers on the fly that have prep-work done (such as one with `npm install` already run).

There are lots of different cases, and it'd be overkill to create an actual `Dockerfile` for each. I'd like to instead be able to just create command-line commands in my script instead.

Comment: Why can't you echo lines out to a temporary Dockerfile from the CLI?

Comment: I was thinking about doing it that way, but I'd like to not actually write the file to the system if I can. I tried the syntax `cmd <( echo 'message')`, but it seems Dockerfile kind of goes boom.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update for 2017-05-05**: Docker just released 17.05.0-ce with this [PR #31236](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/31236) included. Now the above command creates an image:

```
$ docker build -t test-no-df -f - . <<EOF
FROM busybox:latest
CMD echo just a test
EOF
Sending build context to Docker daemon  23.34MB
Step 1/2 : FROM busybox:latest
 ---> 00f017a8c2a6
Step 2/2 : CMD echo just a test
 ---> Running in 45fde3938660
 ---> d6371335f982
Removing intermediate container 45fde3938660
Successfully built d6371335f982
Successfully tagged test-no-df:latest
```

The same can be achieved in a single line with:

```
$ printf 'FROM busybox:latest\nCMD echo just a test' | docker build -t test-no-df -f - .
```

---

**Original Response**

`docker build` requires the Dockerfile to be an actual file. You can use a different filename with:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.temp .
```

They allow the build context (aka the `.` or current directory) to be passed by standard input, but attempting to pass a Dockerfile with this syntax will fail:

```
$ docker build -t test-no-df -f - . <<EOF
FROM busybox:latest
CMD echo just a test
EOF

unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/bmitch/data/docker/test/-: no such file or directory
```

Comment: That's kind of what I was afraid that. That's unfortunately quite lame.

Comment: Reading up on this a bit more, that Dockerfile is the path within the context, so you can dynamically generate your context as a compressed tar file, you can include a Dockerfile inside that that never existed on the filesystem. This moves the challenge of injecting a file from the docker cli to the tar cli.

Comment: Which could potentially work if I was absolutely could not write it to the file system, but gets crazy convoluted if I can but just don't want to.

Comment: Accepting this one as it's the closest to the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @samanime see the latest edit, you may want to check out the latest release.

Answer (score 1):

Build an image from STDIN with no context:

```bash
docker build -t myimage:latest -<<EOF
FROM busybox
RUN echo "hello world"
EOF
```

https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/#text-files

Answer (score 0):

On **Windows** using **PowerShell** the following works (with trailing dash):

```
@'
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y clang zlib1g-dev
'@ | docker build -t 'mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-aot' -
```