# Is it possible to build a docker image using C#

Tags: c#, .net, docker

as the title says, is it possible to build a docker image using C#. im trying to make a button that creates a new docker image based on input from some input fields. But the main question is if it is possible only using code to make a docker image. Without creating a dockerfile?

Comment: Your code could create a dockerfile and then start a process with the docker-cli to get that image created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker build purely from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559126/docker-build-purely-from-command-line)

Comment: not really, looking to use C# code to create a docker image and then from there a container

Comment: Have also looked into creating a dockerfile with code, but this seems like a janky solution really.

Comment: You should be able to use a [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) to invoke the builder programmatically.  You will probably have to provide the build context filesystem tree in some form, which will include a Dockerfile, but it's very possible you won't have to construct it on disk.  As always, remember that being able to interact with Docker at all comes with the ability to launch a container that roots the host, so do be conscious of security concerns.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything but this .NET library can be used to manage an image once it's been created: https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.Dotnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this github repo that is what i was looking for github.com/dotnet/Docker.Dotnet

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).